# Some files are being corrupt in external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, storage

I have the [LaCie Hard Disk Max 2TB](http://www.lacie.com/support/support_manifest.htm?id=10341) .

I've noticed that some of my files (in very rare cases) are corrupted in this storage .
Most of them are songs (.m4a , .mp3) . The only option was to find again those songs because their data was deleted (?) just saw an .m4a file of only 24 bytes .

Also , I noticed that sometimes some files are being used by background programs (which have no idea how to find them , And I am not sure if is by LaCie or some of my programs installed in the computer) So I could not move or change them for short while . 
In last few days there was a short circuit (electricity was shot down for a second) in my apartment so the Hard Drive was also shot down during the background program was accessing the certain files . But it's not first time , many files were corrupt in similar way . I am just afraid that the LaCie drive provides some background processes which can corrupt my files if suddenly turn off the hardware . I am a bit in panic because there are many important files for me such as development projects and other rare private stuff which i have no copies if they lost or corrupt .

I need some help . I don't have any knowledge in storage hardware or how to manage\avoid corruption . 
I was thinking about some Cloud storage service but I don't like it since I need to synchronise everything .
In the meanwhile , I am transferring all my files to the laptop itself which got enough space and showed more reliability than LaCie's reliability .

Comment: What OS you using? using Windows 7?

Comment: Windows 8 Ultimate x64

Comment: When you disconnect you it safely removes?

Comment: @TiagoCA No , I never do it safely . Maybe this is the case ? I disconnected the USB many times suddenly without "safely disconnect" functionality of Windows in the last week , Does it really corrupts files ? But anyway , Why some background applications does accessing my files ? I want to avoid it !

Comment: @DavidDiamond: If you unplug a storage device or removable drive from your computer while it's transferring or saving information, you might risk losing some information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Does it really corrupts files ?***

In theory, it's to ensure that Windows isn't busy reading from or writing to the drive when you remove it, something that could result in corrupted data or even a damaged drive.

[image]

Comment: +1, but I am pretty sure it is not possible to physically damage a drive this way.

Comment: It's not possible to damage the drive but the data stores on the drive can become corrupt

Answer (score 0):

There are many data recovery options for you, [see the answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/611457/contents-of-external-hard-disk-cannot-be-accessed/611535#611535).

Once your data is recovered you will need tools to sift through it. The [Exact Duplicate Finder](http://indeepsoft.blogspot.com/2012/10/exact-duplicate-finder.html) helps you eliminate duplicate files. [Windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) gives you a compehensive view of your files/folders/types and their sizes. There are many [blog posts](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tools-for-getting-rid-of-duplicate-files/) that offer even more options.

Many on-line storage options are available. [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) is the easiest to use. [Skydrive](http://skydrive.com), is another option. [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) offers 15GB shared storage. [Flickr](http://flickr.com) lets you store 1TB of images.

Comment: There is no way to avoid corruption by finding the background process that running in my LaCie hard drive ? Thanks for the information I am looking there right now .

Comment: By the way , I have already signed to 6 Cloud services , In total i have 94.25 GB free space in the cloud for free . I am backing my important files to there . Thanks for Flickr , I didn't knew that they provide 1TB .